# Change value of label in html via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code :

```
<label class='textFontSmall center' for="usr" id="addNameText">BOB</label>
```

And I want the ability to change the text from BOB to Cliff. I have tried 4 different ways :

```
document.getElementById('addNameText').value = 'CLIFF';
document.getElementById('addNameText').text = 'CLIFF';
document.getElementById('addNameText').html = 'CLIFF';
document.getElementById('addNameText').innerHtml = 'CLIFF';
```

None of these work. How come ? I must be missing something simple

https://jsfiddle.net/rukzkaLe/

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
document.getElementById('addNameText').innerText = 'CLIFF';
```

Or this :

```
document.getElementById('addNameText').innerHTML = 'CLIFF';
```

Comment: Please put the code in code blocks (use 4 spaces to indent the code - see my edit). Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle is not a good tool in this case, cause the JavaScript has to be executed after the html:

```
<label class='textFontSmall center' for="usr" id="addNameText">BOB</label>
```

You have an example here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_change_innerhtml

Comment: i looked at that link but obviously I missed typed it. I typed 'innerHtml' rather than 'innerHTML'. Freaking idiot i am. Cheers man

Comment: JavaScript can be executed synchronously on JSFiddle ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/toothbrush7777777/cv6g199m/)).

Answer (score 0):

Use this
     $("#addNameText").text('CLIFF');

Comment: not using JQuery at this moment, but thanks anyway :) I've solved it, was a typo :( answered in comments of another answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this --

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addNameText').html('CLIFF');
});`

Answer (score 0):

After changing the settings of JS Fiddle's second `<select>` list to "no wrap - in <body>" (which means the `<script>` containing the supplied JavaScript (from the JavaScript panel) is inserted into the `<body>` element, as the last-child before the `</body>` closing tag (and therefore is executed after the DOM is constructed, you can simply use:

```
document.getElementById('addNameText').textContent = 'CLIFF';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mLsLtqv5/).

Or, correcting the typo in your call to `innerHTML` (you used the camel-case: `innerHtml`, which is non-existent property of an `HTMLElement`):

```
document.getElementById('addNameText').innerHTML = 'CLIFF';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mLsLtqv5/1/).